# how to pass a button label after a segue in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, segue

I would like to use the title of a button that launches a segue as the title of another button in view that comes up. In the first view, I created 4 buttons contained in an array named Table.
 Then in the second view I have only one button, whose title would be the name of the button that triggered the segue. Here is quick overview of what I did

```
@IBOutlet var Table: [UIButton]!
@IBAction func commanderSegue(sender: AnyObject?) {

    performSegueWithIdentifier("commander", sender: nil)

    print("it works!") }
    override  func prepareForSegue(segue:UIStoryboardSegue, sender:AnyObject?){    
if segue.identifier == "commander" {

    print("we can order!")
        if let nextVC: OrderViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? OrderViewController {

          if let buttonTitle = sender as? UIButton.currentTitle {

            nextVC.tablex.titleLabel.text = buttonTitle

        print("Miam!")
             }  
        }
}
```

But it tells me that 'current title is not a member type of UIButton. How do I fix this? thanks to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button's label is `titleLabel`:

```
let button = sender as! UIButton
if let buttonTitle = button.titleLabel!.text {
    nextVC.buttonText = buttonTitle // Assign the label text to a variable in the next viewController
}
```

In your second VC, you will want:

```
var buttonText: String!
```

And you can then assign that to the next vc's button title:

```
tablex.titleLabel.text = buttonText
```

Comment: Thanks I tried it but it didn't work. I get this message ''fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value''
(lldb)  at the  let button = sender as! UIbutton  statement.  Does it happen because we use ! instead of ? in sender as? Well I'll continue to try different solutions tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

Three things:

1. You should pass the `UIButton` along as the `sender` in `commanderSegue`.  You know your `@IBAction` is connected to a button, so change its type to `UIButton` and replace `nil` with `sender` in the `performSegueWithIdentifier` call.

   ```
   performSegueWithIdentifier("commander", sender: sender)
   ```
2. In `prepareForSegue`, conditionally cast the `sender` to `UIButton` and then call `currentTitle` on that:

   ```
   if let buttonTitle = (sender as? UIButton)?.currentTitle {
   ```
3. The `@IBOutlet`s in the destinationViewController are not set up at `prepareForSegue` time.  To get around this, save the button's title to a property in the destinationViewController called `buttonTitle` and then assign it to the `UILabel` in `viewDidLoad` in the destinationViewController:

   ```
   var buttonTitle = ""

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       tablex.titleLabel.text = buttonTitle
   }
   ```

---

```
@IBOutlet var Table: [UIButton]!
@IBAction func commanderSegue(sender: UIButton) {

    performSegueWithIdentifier("commander", sender: sender)

    print("it works!")
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue:UIStoryboardSegue, sender:AnyObject?) {    
    if segue.identifier == "commander" {

        print("we can order!")
        if let nextVC = segue.destinationViewController as? OrderViewController {

            if let buttonTitle = (sender as? UIButton)?.currentTitle {

                nextVC.buttonTitle = buttonTitle

                print("Miam!")
            }  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks !!!  I used a combination of what you said and also @Shades's advice. As you said the problem was that my sender was nil instead of specifying UIButton. But I must precise that the statement tablex.titleLabel.text = buttonTitle doesn't change the text. It worked when I used tablex.setTitle(buttonTitle, forState: UIControlState.Normal). Of course I had to define buttonTitle as a string with the statement var buttonTitle:String! in the second VC. Thank you guys